# Expected survival time for Weibull proportional hazards model with R's predict.survreg

Tags: r, survival, hazard, weibull-distribution, proportional-hazards

The predictions for a Weibull proportional hazards model from R's `predict.survreg()` are not the expected survival times. Please help me understand this behaviour.

For time $t$, the Weibull density is given, in the parameterisation of `dweibull()`, by

$t\mapsto \left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \left(\frac{t}{b}\right)^{a-1} \exp\left(-\left(\frac{t}{b}\right)^a\right)$

with shape $a$ and scale $b$. Its expectation is $b \Gamma(1 + \frac{1}{a})$. For the Weibull proportional hazards model with proportions $\exp(x^\top C)$, where $x$ are covariates and $C$ coefficients, the density is

$t \mapsto \exp(x^\top C)\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \left(\frac{t}{b}\right)^{a-1} \exp\left(-\exp(x^\top C)\left(\frac{t}{b}\right)^a\right)$

which may be recognised as another Weibull density with shape $a$ and scale $b \exp(-x^\top C)^\frac{1}{a}$. As such, its expectation is $b \exp(-x^\top C)^\frac{1}{a} \Gamma(1 + \frac{1}{a})$. **I expected `predict.survreg()` to output this value, but the multiplication by the gamma function is omitted.**

Minimum working example:

```
require(survival)
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table("covariate" = c(1,2,3), "time" = c(3,5,6))
Weibull <- survreg(Surv(dt$time) ~ dt$covariate, dist = "weibull")

a <- 1 / Weibull$scale # Transform survreg() scale to dweibull() shape.
b <- exp(Weibull$coefficients[1]) # Transform survreg() intercept to dweibull() scale.
C <- - Weibull$coefficients[2] / Weibull$scale # Transform survreg() coefficients (accelerated failure time) to proportional hazard coefficients.

# This is the expectation of the Weibull proportional hazards density.
b * exp(- dt$covariate * C / a) * gamma(1 + 1/a)
# [1] 3.171904 4.485750 6.343808

# This is what predict.survreg() outputs, verified in the predict.survreg() method.
# Notice there is no gamma() function.
b * exp(- dt$covariate * C / a)
# [1] 3.301424 4.668919 6.602849

# This the predict.survreg() call, which indeed returns the same values.
as.numeric(predict(Weibull, data.table(dt$covariate)))
# [1] 3.301424 4.668919 6.602849
```

I am confused, because the sensible prediction for survival time would be its expectation, which requires the gamma function. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is somewhat related to [this question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Weibull-Prediction-td899365.html) and particularly [this question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Survival-Analysis-and-Predict-time-to-death-td4711198.html) and the following answer by Therneau, Terry M.

> 2. The survreg routine assumes that log(y) ~ covariates + error.  For a log-normal  distribion the error is Gaussian and thus the
>      predict(fit, type='response') will be  exp(predicted mean of log
>      time), which is not the predicted mean time.  For Weibull the  error
>      dist is asymmetric so things are more muddy.  Each is the MLE
>      prediction for the  subject, just not interpretable as a mean.  To get
>      the actual mean you need to look up the  formulas for Weibull and/or
>      lognormal in a textbook, and map from the survreg  parameterization to
>      whatever one the textbook uses.  The two parameterizations are never 
>      the same.

So it seems like you should not expect a mean from `predict.survreg`. Göran Broström though do make the same points that you do

> No need for 'the mathematical statistics text': The necessary 
>   information is found on the help page for the Weibull distribution:
>   E(T) 
>   =  b Gamma(1 + 1/a), where 'b' is scale (really!) and 'a' is shape. You  must however take into account the special parametrization that
>   is used  by 'survreg'; see its help page for how to do it.

The above though does make it a bit strange to infer what is meant in `?predict.survreg` by

> `type` the type of predicted value. This can be on the original scale
>   of  the data (response), ...

## Your example

The relevant code is

```
> # look at predict function
> pred_func <- asNamespace("survival")$predict.survreg
> body(pred_func)[23]
(if (type == "lp" || type == "response") {
    if (missing(newdata)) {
        pred <- object$linear.predictors
    }
    else pred <- drop(x %*% coef) + offset
    if (se.fit) 
        se <- sqrt(diag(x %*% vv %*% t(x)))
    if (type == "response") {
        pred <- itrans(pred)
        if (se.fit) 
            se <- se/dtrans(pred)
    }
} else ...
> 
> # this is the function that is used
> dd <- survreg.distributions[["weibull"]]
> dd$itrans
function (x) 
exp(x)
<bytecode: 0x000000001e07ef00>
<environment: namespace:survival>
```