# Mean Survival Time Under Weibull Model Using `survreg`

Tags: r, survival, weibull-distribution

Under the Weibull parametric model, we assume the survival time $T \sim \text{Weibull}(\alpha, \lambda)$, with density $f_T(t) = \alpha \lambda (\lambda t)^{\alpha - 1} \exp(-(\lambda t)^\alpha)$. Then the mean would be $ET = \Gamma(1+1/\alpha)/\lambda$ (from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), although they use $1/\lambda$ for the scale and $k$ for the shape). I'm trying to fit a Weibull model to a dataset, but I find there's a discrepancy between the estimated mean survival time from the model, and the mean I calculate using the fitted parameters:

```
> library(survival)
> data(kidney)
> m <- survreg(Surv(time,status)~1,data=kidney[kidney$sex==1,],dist="weibull")
> predict(m)[1]
[1] 50.37909 # estimate from the model
> summary(m)
> alpha <- 1/m$scale
> lambda <- 1/exp(m$coef)
> gamma(1+1/alpha)/lambda
[1] 62.0962  # my calculation using the formula for expected value
```

What's the reason for this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of your calculations is correct. You can verify this with a simple simulation:

```
> set.seed(1234)
> mean(rweibull(1e5, shape = alpha, scale = 1/lambda))
[1] 62.00408
```

`predict.survreg` does not return the expected survival time. For details see for example [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/314408/232102) answer.