# R Survival Survreg Predict with "response" type

Tags: regression, survival, predictive-models

I have contradictory output when using R survival analysis predictions with the "response" type.

I coded the following and ran:

```
y <- rweibull(1000, shape=2, scale=exp(4))
e <- rep(1, 1000)
mean(y)     # 49.50
median(y)   # 46.40

library(survival)
model <- survreg(Surv(y, e) ~ 1)
summary(model)

predict(model, type="response", newdata=data.frame(1))             # 55.87
predict(model, type="quantile", newdata=data.frame(1), p=c(0.5))   # 46.54
```

However, I checked the output with the expected value and median of the fitted Weibull:

```
scale <- exp(model$coef[1]); scale; log(scale)
shape <- 1/model$scale; shape
expected <- scale*gamma(1+1/shape); expected                       # 49.51
med <- qweibull(0.5, shape=shape, scale=scale); med                # 46.54
```

In sum, the quantiles coincides but the expected values differ. What `predict.survreg` with `type="response"` does?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please take a look at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/303202/28500), which I think answers yours. Section 4.6.1 of the [survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf) notes that for a Weibull distribution what's returned is the exponential of the linear predictor. That's not the same as the mean of the distribution. What you get in your case is approximately `exp(4)`. If there's still something unclear, please edit the question to specify what that is.

Comment: Thank you. You are right!

Comment: Glad we could help. It's policy to label a question as a "duplicate" when there's already an answer on the site, but your question (with its helpful code) will still be visible.